# how to write a method correctly that returns a given array

Tags: arrays, scala, mapping

hello I am a Scala newbie I want to write a function that gets a double array(for the example ill name it xs) and the function returns another double array that each double inside the new array that I am returning will be the the possibly of the number showing in the xs array that is given I am new to scala syntax

for example:
xs array is : (1,2,3,4,5)
the returned array is : (0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)

another example:
Array(14.0,14.0,1.0,2.0) // values returned
Array(0.5,0.5,0.25,0.25)// possibilities

arrays

```
def probs(xs: Array[Double]):Array[Double] = xs.distinct.map(f=>{
  prob(xs,f);
});
  def prob(xs: Array[Double], num: Double):Double = xs.count(x=>x==num)*1.0/xs.length
```

can someone help me fix it so it can work properly thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to write a function and return a given array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844944/how-to-write-a-function-and-return-a-given-array)

Comment: no it dosent =\

Comment: You shouldn't remove your old questions and repost them with changes. Also your code works if you remove `.distinct`, although it's inefficient

Answer (score 0):

```
def probs(xs: Array[Double]): Array[Double]={
    val counts=xs.groupBy(identity)
    xs.map(x=> counts(x).size.toDouble/xs.size)
}
```